# How to plot time on the x-axis of a scatter plot for every minute

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime, x-axis

Setting minute minor ticks for 1-second sampled data raises: `OverflowError: int too big to convert`

Consider this dataframe with a sample interval of 1 second that spans about 30 minutes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MinuteLocator
import pandas as pd

ndex = pd.date_range('2021-08-01 07:07:07', '2021-08-01 07:41:12', freq='1S', name='Time') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(1, 100, len(ndex)), index=ndex, columns=['A'])
```

And now we plot it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(color='red', marker='x', lw=0, ms=0.2, ax=ax)
```

Which creates a plot without any complaints:
[image: time vs randint]

Now I'd like to have minor ticks at every minute.

I've tried this:

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MinuteLocator())
```

But that fails with `OverflowError: int too big to convert`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) uses `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend,  but it encodes date ticks as unix timestamps, which results in `OverflowError: int too big to convert`.

  - The default here is `kind='line'`, but `marker='x', lw=0, ms=0.2` are used in the OP to make a hacky scatter plot.
- [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) will work correctly.
- Using [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) will work as expected.

  - [matplotlib: Date tick labels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html)

    - *Matplotlib date plotting is done by converting date instances into days since an epoch (by default 1970-01-01T00:00:00)*
- [`seaborn.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) will also work:

  - `sns.scatterplot(x=df.index, y=df.A, color='red', marker='x', ax=ax)`
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.2`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`

- The extra formatting has the effect of removing the month (`'01'`) that would precede the time in the tick labels (e.g. `'%m %H:%M'`).

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 6))
ax.scatter(x=df.index, y=df.A, color='red', marker='x')

hourlocator = mdates.HourLocator(interval=1)  # adds some extra formatting, but not required
majorFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')  # adds some extra formatting, but not required

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator())

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFmt)  # adds some extra formatting, but not required
_ = plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image]

### `pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter`

- Also `pandas.DataFrame.plot` with `kind='scatter'`

  - `ax = df.reset_index().plot(kind='scatter', x='Time', y='A', color='red', marker='x', figsize=(25, 6), rot=90)`

```py
# reset the index so Time will be a column to assign to x
ax = df.reset_index().plot.scatter(x='Time', y='A', color='red', marker='x', figsize=(25, 6), rot=90)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator())
```

[image]

---

- Note the difference in the xticks produced by the two methods

### `pandas.DataFrame.plot` `xticks`

```py
ax = df.plot(color='red', marker='x', lw=0, ms=0.2, figsize=(25, 6))

# extract the xticks to see the format
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
print(ticks)
[out]:
array([1627801627, 1627803672], dtype=int64)

# convert the column to unix format to compare
(df.index - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1s')

[out]:
Int64Index([1627801627, 1627801628, 1627801629, 1627801630, 1627801631,
            1627801632, 1627801633, 1627801634, 1627801635, 1627801636,
            ...
            1627803663, 1627803664, 1627803665, 1627803666, 1627803667,
            1627803668, 1627803669, 1627803670, 1627803671, 1627803672],
           dtype='int64', name='Time', length=2046)
```

### `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` `xticks`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 6))
ax.scatter(x=df.index, y=df.A, color='red', marker='x')

ticks2 = ax.get_xticks()
print(ticks2)

[out]:
array([18840.29861111, 18840.30208333, 18840.30555556, 18840.30902778,
       18840.3125    , 18840.31597222, 18840.31944444])
```